# When to see vet? Snake digestion process stuck

Tags: health, snakes, digestion

I fed my 5 year old adult carpet python 2 weeks ago. He still has a large bump right in the middle of his midsection. He is last poop was around the same time he was fed. I plan to go to the vet in about a week. Should I be concerned about going sooner? I've given him mineral oil in the past to help him pass food quickly, but since the food seems to be blocked early in his system I don't want to just back him up more.

Comment: How often does he eat usually? How often doe she poop usually? How much time does it take usually, for the "bump" to go away?

Comment: They usually eat every 3-4 weeks. Now it's been about 4 weeks. He pooped 1 mid size yesterday, but still a major bulge that looks like almost like the corner of a cube. The lump is usually gone after a few days. They usually poop major all week in the week after eating, but he only pooped 2 mid sized 3 weeks ago.